# Compilation error: Cannot find symbol FragmentBindingImpl with custom attributes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have data binding elsewhere and this is the only place where it's giving me these issues I don't have dagger. If I remove the lines in this view that use data binding I get no errors and can install on my device. I've tried every combination of rebuilding/restarting and clearing caches and deleting build files. I also tried disabling data binding and reenabling it.

Here's the layout file I'm using called `fragment_subscription.xml`

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <data>

    <variable name="fragment" type="com.example.subscription.SubscriptionFragment"/>

    <variable name="week" type="com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails"/>
    <variable name="month" type="com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails"/>
    <variable name="year" type="com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails"/>

  </data>

<com.example.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/week_subscription_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:presetButtonPriceText="@{week.price}"
                app:presetButtonUnitText="@string/week_subscription_unit"
                app:presetButtonValueText="@string/week_subscription_value"/>

        <com.example.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/month_subscription_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:presetButtonPriceText="@{month.price}"
                app:presetButtonUnitText="@string/month_subscription_unit"
                app:presetButtonValueText="@string/month_subscription_value"/>

        <com.example.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/year_subscription_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:presetButtonPriceText="@{year.price}"
                app:presetButtonUnitText="@string/year_subscription_unit"
                app:presetButtonValueText="@string/year_subscription_value"/>

</layout>
```

Here are my custom button specific view attributes

```
    <attr name="presetButtonUnitText" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="presetButtonPriceText" format="string"/>
    <attr name="presetButtonValueText" format="integer"/>
```

Here is where I create my view in `SubscriptionFragment.kt`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return FragmentSubscriptionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).let {
        this.binding = it
        bind(skuDetailsList)
        it.root
    }
}
```

Here's where I bind my view

```
private fun bind(skuList: MutableList<SkuDetails>) {
    binding?.let {
        if (skuList.isNotEmpty()) {
            it.week = skuList[0]
            it.month = skuList[1]
            it.year = skuList[2]
            it.fragment = SubscriptionFragment@this
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried adding these lines in my apps' gradle.properties

```
android.databinding.enableV2 = true
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = true
```

I have added these to my apps' gradle

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I was binding to custom attributes and needed to set custom getters/setters in the custom view I inflated

EDIT:

Example

```
public class ColorPicker extends View {
    private int color;

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

//...
}
```

Here's what the xml looks like

```
<com.example.myapp.ColorPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:color="@{color}"/>
```